Why isn't there an error fixer in c/c++ for include files that don't exist?
There is a lot of difficulty in differentiating between operating systems in c/c++. That said, I've noticed that there are very specific libraries for different operating systems, windows.h in windows, unist.h or time.h in linux, etc...
Why isn't it used?:
#tryinclude
#include "win-app.c"
#catch
#include "unix-app.c"
#endtry

int main(){...}


How do I check OS with a preprocessor directive?, maybe?

"Why?" is not a really good question for SO :-)

@001 Not only would it be useful on different operating systems, but also on different compilers.

Is the C++17 has __has_include any help? See the answer C++ try statement won't work with "#include"

Windows is Windows, Linux is Linux. There isn't a one-to-one mapping of APIs between them, so I don't see how this would help much.
